# How to add "-lib /my/lib" when running Ant programmatically?

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to run **Ant** script programmatically from **Java** code, using **org.apache.tools.ant** library.

This works fine, unless I have some externally defined task.

Let's assume my build.xml looks as follows:

```
<project name="sample" basedir="." default="all">
    <target name="all">
        <echo>Ant From Java</echo>
    </target>
    <taskdef name="mytask" classname="my.task.Mytask" /> 
</project>
```

and that I have my a file **mylib.jar** that contains **my.task.Mytask** class in **/home/mylib** directory

The script obviously works when I run it with following command:

```
ant all -lib /home/mylib
```

but not with this one

```
ant all
```

In the Java code it is quite easy to deploy Ant in the later way, using

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper;
....
....
    String buildXmlFile = "/home/build.xml";
    Project project = new Project();
    File buildFile = new File(buildXmlFile);
    project.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());        
    project.fireBuildStarted();
    project.init();
    ProjectHelper projectHelper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
    project.addReference("ant.projectHelper", projectHelper);
    projectHelper.parse(project, buildFile);
    project.executeTarget("all");
    project.fireBuildFinished(null);
```

But I am not able to find "**-lib /home/mylib**" equivalent in the **org.apache.tools.ant** library.

I am almost sure it should be somewhere there, but I have been trying without success, and maybe someone knows a simple solution to my problem.

I would appreiciate any help!

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that it's out there. It most likely has to do with classloaders and these things are usually provided upfront to the JVM (I haven't checked how Ant loads its libraries, it could be done dynamically).

Comment: Well, my coleague found one solution. It is sufficient to add libraries which are to be added to "-lib " to the project build path, and the ant will run without trouble. 

But now the next problem arises, because I want to build the project with maven build without info about the directory of the jars to include.

Comment: Maven can manage the dependencies for you. The antrun plugin provides a mechanism for ANT to access the managed classpaths. See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html

Comment: Thanks for good advice! I would certainly do it this way, but I am developing a Jenkins plugin, and therefore my maven is already set up in some predefined way, and when I change it something crashes during build execution ;-).